# Retrieve image url from database and display in React using Material-UI

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of movies and I want to display the name of the movie and the image attached to that movie. I got image URLs from the web and put them inside an MySQL database(varchar300).

```
const MovieView = (props: { movie: Movie; }) => {
  const {movie} = props;

  return (
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}
           className="movie">
        <Link to={`movies/${movie.id}`}>
          <Paper elevation={3} className="movie-paper">
            <div>
              <h2>{movie.title}</h2>
              <img src="movie.image" alt=""/>
            </div>
          </Paper>
        </Link>
      </Grid>
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you need the src to be in template form (using squiggly brackets {}) instead of quotes. Try this instead

```js
const MovieView = (props: { movie: Movie; }) => {
  const {movie} = props;

  return (
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={3}
           className="movie">
        <Link to={`movies/${movie.id}`}>
          <Paper elevation={3} className="movie-paper">
            <div>
              <h2>{movie.title}</h2>
              <img src={movie.image} alt=""/>
            </div>
          </Paper>
        </Link>
      </Grid>
    );
}
```

Comment: Sure thing, don't forget to accept the answer if it answered everything! :)